# How to bypass DRIVER_PNP_WATCHDOG during Windows installation?

Tags: windows, bios, windows-11, windows-installation, pnp

I have a DELL Vostro laptop at home. For some reason, it has windows boot loader but there are no files on the disk. So I made a bootable usb using rufus (I set everything correctly, GPT and UEFI settings in BIOS as well. My SATA mode is AHCI (we cannot change it in bios). So on booting from the usb drive, the setup loads for some 5 mins and then I get the blue screen of death with the stopcode: DRIVER_PNP_WATCHDOG. The setup never started.

I researched a bit on this and found out that this happens when windows initialises the pnp devices and one of it fails. Now I don't see any hardware failing, maybe something is failing but there's no way to check.

For checking, I tried to run Ubuntu installer using the same usb drive and it works fine. I also tried many other copies of Windows 11 from different sources but all gave the same error.

So what should I do now? How do I bypass this pnp device check and get the setup to run? Thank you

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcqPw.png)

Comment: Windows 11 requires Secure Boot.

Comment: Tried with that too @ChanganAuto . I'll update my question

Comment: OK, and what about other Windows 11 requirements? I've assumed the machine is new enough to support Windows 11, the only issue being the disabled Secure Boot (for no reason) but now I'm not so sure...

Comment: 1. Is it approved for Windows 11, https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000187485/dell-computers-tested-for-upgrade-to-windows-11? 2. Using MS Create Windows 11 Installation Media, https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11/ , might succeed where Rufus does not.

Comment: The machine was shipped with Windows 11 @ChanganAuto . It was running fine earlier, but someone messed up and now I can't find out what's the issue here

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I didn't check with the Microsoft one, I'll try that and update. Thankyou